# "The named parameter keyboardDismissBehavior isn't defined" without pull_to_refresh

Tags: flutter, singlechildscrollview

As the title, I got a error message that the singleChildScrollView does not has keyboardDismissBehavior property. Some articles said that this issue is caused by the version of pull_to_refresh package. But I didn't use that package in my project. Please help.

[Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRljM.png)

Comment: What's your Flutter version?

Comment: @enzo My version is v1.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Flutter docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/release-notes-2.2.0), the `keyboardDismissBehavior` parameter is only available in Flutter after v2.2.0:

> [76312](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/76312) add keyboardDismissBehavior into SingleChildScrollView (cla: yes, f: scrolling, framework, waiting for tree to go green)

To fix this, just [upgrade your Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading):

```
flutter upgrade
```